# How to take data from a google sheets API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm a highschooler working on a website. We have a google sheets with log in information. Its connected to javascript. I was wondering how do I redirect this data to be used in html (which has the bulk of the project).

I've really been at a loss

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `We have a google sheets with log in information. Its connected to javascript. I was wondering how do I redirect this data to be used in html (which has the bulk of the project).`. In order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result? By the way, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.